# Exposed filter of content type set to related term

Tags: 7, views

I have used Taxonomy term template in views to show **ContentType-A*. While **ContentType-A** has a field reference for **ContentType-B**, and I want to use **ContentType-B** as exposed filter. The problem with this filter that it shows all its content, and I wanted to be limited to terms it is set to.

So how to show only **contentType-B** as exposed filter, related to current term?

FYI: the taxonomy term view already has following contextual filters settings:

```
/* Contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['id'] = 'term_node_tid_depth';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['field'] = 'term_node_tid_depth';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['default_action'] = 'not found';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['exception']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['title'] = '%1';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['validate']['type'] = 'taxonomy_term';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['depth'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['break_phrase'] = TRUE;
/* Contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['id'] = 'term_node_tid_depth_modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['field'] = 'term_node_tid_depth_modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['exception']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
```